# shell script: ffmpeg can't either read arguments or filenames, if spaces in path- or filename

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm currently working on a bash shell script  on OS X to get a custom tailored [Pashua](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/) GUI/automatization package, using ffmpeg in the back, to transcode videos, label them, zip them, upload them, organize them and so on. Everything is working like a charm so far.

My problem now is that I can't make ffmpeg take files or paths that have spaces in them IF I use variables in variables. But that (I think) is a must in order to get ffmpeg to transcode multiple files at once depending on the formats and checkboxes the user ticks on.

I made a little example snippet so you can see my dilemma.

**No spaces in path or filename / works great:**

```
#!/bin/bash

infile='/Users/nicolas/Desktop/MASTER_[DE]_Test_140626.mov'

gen_outfile () {
    outfile="${1/MASTER/TRANSCODE}"
    ffmpeg_cl="-s $2 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 240k -strict -2 $outfile"
}

gen_outfile "$infile" 1920x1080

./ffmpeg_stat -i "$infile" $ffmpeg_cl
```

The output is as expected and the file is called "TRANSCODE_[DE]_Test_140626.mov"

**Filename variable with spaces - directly fed to ffmpeg:**

This works as well but isn't really usable for me because I need to have the option of variable numbers of output files and arguments generated dynamically.

```
#!/bin/bash

infile_full='/Users/nicolas/Google Drive/encode-o-mat/MASTER_[DE] Test  140626.mov'

gen_outfile () {
    outfile="${1/MASTER/TRANSCODE}"
    ffmpeg_cl="-s $2 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 240k -strict -2"
}

gen_outfile "$infile_full" 1920x1080

./ffmpeg_stat -i "$infile_full" $ffmpeg_cl "$outfile"
```

The output is as expected and the file is called "TRANSCODE_[DE] Test  140626.mov".
But this way is just not an option.

**This here does not work! Filename is split up and incomplete:**

```
#!/bin/bash

infile_full='/Users/nicolas/Google Drive/encode-o-mat/MASTER_[DE] Test  140626.mov'

gen_outfile () {
    outfile="${1/MASTER/TRANSCODE}"
    ffmpeg_cl="-s $2 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 240k -strict -2 $outfile"
}

gen_outfile "$infile_full" 1920x1080

./ffmpeg_stat -i "$infile_full" $ffmpeg_cl
```

Ffmpeg gives this error: *"Unable to find a suitable output format for '/Users/nicolas/Google'".*
Of course.

**This doesn't work as well! Quoting and such:**

```
./ffmpeg_stat -i "$infile_full" "$ffmpeg_cl"
```

If I put the $ffmpeg_cl variable in various quotes ffmpeg doesn't understand the arguments anymore! This is one example output:

*"Unrecognized option 's 1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 240k -strict -2 /Users/nicolas/Google Drive/encode-o-mat/TRANSCODE_[DE] Test  140626.mov'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
Conversion failed!"*

It's really important that the script can handle path- and filenames with spaces because I can't change the environment in which that tool is supposed to run. All ideas and solutions are more than welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use arrays instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

infile_full='/Users/nicolas/Google Drive/encode-o-mat/MASTER_[DE] Test  140626.mov'

gen_outfile () {
    outfile="${1/MASTER/TRANSCODE}"
    ffmpeg_cl=(-s "$2" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 240k -strict -2 "$outfile")
}

gen_outfile "$infile_full" 1920x1080

./ffmpeg_stat -i "$infile_full" "${ffmpeg_cl[@]}"
```

Make sure you quote arguments with variable expansions around `""` properly. Also quote any argument containing `*`, `?`, `!`, `[` and `]`.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thank you so much! I wonder why though. What's - in this case - the difference between an array and a variable?

Comment: @Nicolas Perhaps what you mean is the difference between an array variable between a standard variable. Standard variables simply can hold normal values but array variables can hold values without giving conflict to other values by indices. Array variables are helpful in this case so that you won't need to depend on word splitting to separate arguments which is rather difficult when some arguments has spaces between that you wouldn't want to split. Word splitting also is subject  to pathname or filename expansion and could even give different results if some parts of the word is a valid glob.

Comment: Oh! I see! ffmpeg_cl as an array has 17 values! Not 1! But I still not see the difference between
    ffmpeg_cl[16]='/Users/nicolas/Google Drive/encode-o-mat/MASTER_[DE] Test  140626.mov'
and
    ffmpeg_cl='/Users/nicolas/Google Drive/encode-o-mat/MASTER_[DE] Test  140626.mov'
in case of how it holds the value.
I guess I have to read more on "variable expansion" to fully understand the problem.